# react hooks for returning different functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Building a ticket system for a movie app to learn react.
I've been trying to wrap my head around the useState and react hooks to make my seating system return an occupied seat after getting clicked on if it is vacant. What am I missing to make this work?

```
const PurchaseTicket = () => {
  const seat = () => {
    return (
      <div className=' cursor-pointer bg-gray-500 h-[24px] w-[30px] m-1 rounded-t-[10px]'></div>
    )
  }

  const seatOccupied = () => {
    return (
      <div className=' bg-cyan-500 h-[24px] w-[30px] m-1 rounded-t-[10px]'></div>
    )
  }

  const [seating, setSeating] = useState([seat()])

  const vacancy = () => {
    setSeating((seatOccupied()))
  }

  const sideRow = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="m-auto pt-10 flex flex-row">
        <div onClick={vacancy}>{seating}</div>
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='m-15 flex flex-row justify-evenly'>
        <div>{sideRow()}</div>
        <div>{middleRow()}</div>
        <div>{sideRow()}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

React hook `useState` in this case, can store value of **any type** with special behaviour for functions as said in the [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#parameters).

Here, we add additional `vacant` state (you can use whatever name you like).

```
const PurchaseTicket = () => {
  const seat = () => {
    return (
      <div className="cursor-pointer bg-gray-500 h-[24px] w-[30px] m-1 rounded-t-[10px]" />
    )
  }

  const seatOccupied = () => {
    return (
      <div className=" bg-cyan-500 h-[24px] w-[30px] m-1 rounded-t-[10px]" />
    )
  }

  const [seating, setSeating] = useState(seat)
  const [vacant, setVacant] = useState(true)

  const vacancy = () => {
    setVacant((prev) => !prev)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setSeating(vacant ? seat : seatOccupied);
  }, [vacant])

  return (
    <>
      ...
      <div onClick={vacancy}>{seating}</div>
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```

but keep in mind that both `seat` and `seatOccupied` should be pure, should take no arguments.

But I myself, prefers to extract the seat and seatOccupied as separate components

```
function Seat() {
  return (
    <div className="cursor-pointer bg-gray-500 h-[24px] w-[30px] m-1 rounded-t-[10px]" />
  )
}

function SeatOccupied() {
  return <div className="bg-cyan-500 h-[24px] w-[30px] m-1 rounded-t-[10px]" />
}
```

and render it with conditional rendering:

```
  return (
    <>
      ...
      <div onClick={vacancy}>{!vacant ? <SeatOccupied /> : <Seat />}</div>
      ...
    </>
  )
```

or:

```
function Seat({ vacant }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`${!vacant ?"bg-cyan-500" : "cursor-pointer bg-gray-500"} h-[24px] w-[30px] m-1 rounded-t-[10px]`}
    />
  )
}
```

and render it like this:

```
return (
    <>
      ...
      <div onClick={vacancy}>
        <Seat vacant={vacant} />
      </div>
      ...
    </>
  )
```

So, you can choose whatever you like.

You can see my example [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sparkling-framework-fh7nh4?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq000a3b6h6lbsola1%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00033b6hzo566kp5%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00073b6hpnzx8m4a%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00093b6hu8rj5xob%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60.74026502120299%252C39.25973497879701%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cloz5k4aq00033b6hzo566kp5%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00033b6hzo566kp5%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cloz636uo00av3b6hy1f8xepj%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4ap00023b6hgpie7240%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz636uo00av3b6hy1f8xepj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz6vqsr01g83b6hfbpuf58l%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cloz5k4aq00093b6hu8rj5xob%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00083b6hq6jxn5k6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00093b6hu8rj5xob%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00083b6hq6jxn5k6%2522%257D%252C%2522cloz5k4aq00073b6hpnzx8m4a%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00043b6hzka17498%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00053b6h2sa2w47n%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00063b6hpwb8t1aw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522preview%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00073b6hpnzx8m4a%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cloz5k4aq00043b6hzka17498%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)